# Induction proof of inequality from linear recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Consider the sequence:

$a_0 = 1; a_1 = 2; a_2 = 3; a_k = a_{k-1} + a_{k-2} + a_{k-3}; k \geq 3$
and the statement
$P(n) : a_n \leq 2^n$. Prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $P(n)$ holds.

I would like some help understanding this question. Also which is the best way to approach this question with 'Simple Induction' or 'Strong Induction'.

Comment: Your math is completely unreadable on my phone. Please use Mathjax. You can find info in the help center. Weird Unicode tricks are a bad plan here...

Comment: The question is a little mistyped. But if I could get it right, you'll have to use strong induction, since the recurrence relation defining $a_n$, depends not only on $a_{n-1}$.

Comment: sorry let me try to fix the question

Comment: Understood the recurrence relation, but not the statement and the proof required.

Comment: sorry guys I need to edit this first

Comment: alright I fixed it as much as I could

Comment: Do you mean $a_n\le 2^n$?

Comment: yes sir that is what I meant

Comment: I just edited it to make use of some of the more "obscure" MathJax symbols.  Please make sure this is what you wanted.  (I wrote $\Bbb{Z}^\text{nonneg}$ instead of $\Bbb{N}$ because you said that $0\in\Bbb{N}$.)

Comment: Oh--Strong induction is what you want here, for the reason that Mateus Sampaio listed.

Comment: @anorton .. thanks for the edit, the question sheet I have just says N and N includes 0 ... now that I look closer I dont even think this N is a natural number. It doesn't have the extra line in it.

Comment: @MateusSampaio, thanks for the answer ! Could you please elaborate on your answer please. I am very weak at discrete math.

Comment: Opinions vary as to whether $0\in\Bbb N$, unfortunately.

Comment: @dfeuer what do u mean by 'Opinions vary as to whether 0∈N'

Comment: @Martin, different people use the same symbol, $\Bbb N$, to refer to different sets. Some use it to refer to the set of weakly positive integers (better known as non-negative integers), while others use it to refer to the set of (strictly) positive integers. It's nice to include $0$, because then $\Bbb N$ can be identified with the set of finite ordinals, but others don't do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We check that $P(n)$ is true for $n\leq 2$, by direct inspection. Assume it is valid for $n\leq k-1$. Then we have
$$a_k=a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-3}\leq 2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}+2^{k-3}=2^{k-3}(2^2+2^1+2^0)=2^{k-3}(4+2+1)= 7\cdot2^{k-3}<8 \cdot2^{k-3}=2^k$$
So, we prooved that if $P(n)$ holds for $n\leq k-1$, it also holds for $n=k$, since we obtained $a_k<2^k$. By the (strong) iduction principle, we showed that is valid $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: one more question why do we have 2^(k-1)+2^(k-2)+2^(k-3)=2^(k-3)(4+2+1)

Comment: I understand where we get the (4+2+1) ... but why do we multiply that with 2^(k-3)?

Comment: Added one more step. This equality is reached taking $2^{k-3}$ in evidence.

Comment: why do we write this step 7.2^(k-3) < 8.2^(k-3)

Comment: We do this because we want to obtain $2^k$ in the other side of the inequality.

Comment: sorry to bug u so much ... but if we want 2^k on the other side of the equation. Then how would the algebra look like?

Comment: Didn't understand your doubt. The strategy of a strong induction proof is to show that a property that holds for all $n\leq k-1$, also holds for $k$. In this case, the property is $a_n\leq 2^n$. So, we want to show that $a_k\leq 2^k$. That's why I used the manipulations, to get $2^k$ in the RHS, from $a_k$ in the LHS.